# Problems translating sentences to logical notation and negating them

Tags: logic

The question goes like "For each of the following sentences, write down the sentence in logical notation, negate the sentence, and say whether the sentence or its negation is true:
c)  Every even number is a sum of two odd numbers."

The best answer I was able to come up with:
x((x mod 2 = 0)  yz(y +z)) where our domain is all real numbers.
Can someone please help me confirm whether or not my answer is correct?

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide will help you improve your formatting. As it stands, I can't distinguish your $\exists$ (`\exists`) from your $\forall$ (`\forall`) or $\implies$ (`\implies`).

Comment: All real numbers, really ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positive:

$$\forall\ e\in\mathbb Z: \exists\ o_1,o_2\in\mathbb Z:2e=(2o_1+1)+(2o_2+1).$$

Negative:

$$\exists\ e\in\mathbb Z: \forall\ o_1,o_2\in\mathbb Z:2e\ne(2o_1+1)+(2o_2+1).$$

The positive is true, by taking $o_1=e,o_2=-1$, which is always possible.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to make $y,\,z$ being odd explicit (as well as to include an $x=$), so the original statement should be $\forall x(x\equiv0(\bmod2)\implies\exists y\exists z(y\equiv z\equiv1(\bmod2)),\,x=y+z)$. I'll leave the other parts as an exercise.